# Stop object detail page from refreshing at click of a button on embedded visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

At the window.onload() event of a standard object detail page I am storing the time value in one of its fields. I have embedded a vf page along with this detail page. At the click of a button in the embedded vf page shown,the object detail page refreshes and the window.onload event resets the value to the new time stored in the object field. Is there a way to stop the detail page from refreshing?

Just adding snippets of the code here :

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() 
    {
        sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
        var aResult = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Time__c FROM card__c where Id = {!card__c.Id}");
        /*code to update the time filed on the object*/
</script>
<script>
    function abc()  
    {
        /*Some DML Operations here*/
    }
</script>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
           <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Do Something" onclick="abc" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code please ?

Comment: Hi I have added a little bit of the code to give you an idea of what I am trying to do. Whenever I click the do something  button the object detail page refreshes. The onload function in the script works perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `return false;` to your `onclick` function. Without that the page will reload after clicking.

Another solution is to add an `rerender="none"` tparameter to the command button.

So it will look like this:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Do Something" onclick="abc(); return false;" />
```

or like this:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Do Something" onclick="abc(); reRender="none" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
<apex:commandButton value="Do Something" onclick="abc()" />
```

to :

```
<apex:commandButton value="Do Something" onclick="abc(); return false;" />
```